# how to set a value forever in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, global

I'm new in node js.
I want to save an id in a global variable. 
I need that in many functions.
But when server restart the variable get empty.
Is there any way to save my required value for a long time even when server restart?

Comment: You should consider storing those variables in persistent storage like **File** or **DB**, and when server restarts, just read those values from **File** or **DB** and set it to your global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store variables as environmental variables, so that they can load each time you restart your server. or you can have them in file system or in database.

1. Environment variables can be set command line as [node.js process variable](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) and read them anywhere in you node code with process.env.[variable_name]
2. You can write your variables in file and read them using [FS module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options)
3. Or you can have you variables in database as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the variable using `Store-js`

To save the value using store js
npm install store-js;

```
import store from 'store-js';
store.set('variable', value);//for saving value
store.get('variable');// for getting of the value
```